# What EOS Chain Information/Interaction do you wish was more publicly available?

Tags: voting, ram, bandwidth, cpu, explorer

I've decided to build a website that will display chain metrics as it relates to EOSIO.  I am thinking of integrating with Scatter.

My initial ideas are to show:

1. Cost Per Byte of RAM currently and historically

   - Buy/Sell RAM using Scatter
2. Min/AVG/Max CPU & Bandwidth Achievable per EOS token

   - Stake then buy/sell CPU/Bandwidth using Scatter
3. Current highest bidding namespace suffix (also show historically what has won)

   - Ability to vote on premium names with Scatter
   - Show historical namespace auctions
   - Explorer for claimed/unclaimed suffix's **(Lau)**
4. Cost Calculators (if you have an idea for one, please share!)

   - For creating account **(Lau)**
5. BP Voting Data

   - Perhaps include total EOS income per producer
   - Other public info such as: (hardware, website..)
   - How Long BP has been active **(TeeAttack42)**
   - How many DPoS turns missed **(TeeAttack42)**
   - Voting history (for freezing accounts, protocol/constitution changes, account code change)  **(TeeAttack42)**
   - Let me know what other voting metrics/information would be helpful
6. EOS Storage stats once available **(TeeAttack42)**

If you have any additional ideas, please share them below!

Comment: **1. Cost Per Byte of RAM currently and historically
Buy/Sell RAM using Scatter** how do you get historical RAM prices from cleos?

Comment: https://www.feexplorer.io/EOS_RAM_price
https://www.eosrp.io/

So I did some looking into how the second site does it since it's open source and I found this: https://github.com/eosnewyork/erp/blob/master/backend/batchpriceupdater/src/com/eosrp/resources/EosResources.java

Which led me to what you want which is the command:

cleos -u https://nodes.get-scatter.com:443 get table eosio eosio rammarket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great idea, I would love to use that.
If you need any help, I may use some spare time to participate.

in addition to 5. voting:

- stats for BPs (e.g. how long have they have been active as BP, missed DPoS turns etc.)
- history of voting for freezing accounts, change account code, protocol/constitution changes

8) When added to EOSIO, information about EOS Storage and IPFS, maybe some explorer tool

Comment: Thank you for those additions and willingness to contribute!  I tagged your ideas as well.  I'm likely going to boil this list down before starting, but I want it to be a good start and representative of what developers could actually use.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick shot:

3. Search for blocked/still available names and namespaces like it's done when buying an domain online
4. Cost calculator for creating an account

Comment: Thank you for that.  I like the idea of being able to search for a name like a domain name.  I've added your comments!